# Javascript Select2 Show Placeholder

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

Code(HTML)

```
<select id="example" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Code(SCRIPT)

```
$('#example').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
```

What i want:

Before Selection, i wanted it to show placeholder "Select a month"

Requirement

> Don't want to add additional value into html code , all purely on the
>   script.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ojczr91/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you can not change the HTML Code, so you would need to create a Select Option yourself and also mark it as selected. Below is the JS code

```
$('#example').prepend('<option selected="selected"></option>');
$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
```

Here is a working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ojczr91/)

Comment: Thanks , this is what i need

Answer (score 3):

If you add an empty `<option></option>` to the start of your select, it will work.

```
<select id="example" style="width: 300px">
  <option></option>
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
</select>
```

The documentation regarding `select2` and placeholders can be found [here](https://select2.org/placeholders)

**Working demo**

```js
$('#example').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month',
  allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select id="example" style="width: 300px">
  <option></option>
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Greedo year i know the source, was editing the answer.

Comment: did not want to be rude, just to clarify for the questioner

Comment: @Greedo I know, I'm just informing you that I was adding it.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the placeholder value to appear, you must have a blank  as the first option in your  control. This is because the browser tries to select the first option by default. If your first option were non-empty, the browser would display this instead of the placeholder.

```
<select id="example" class="exx" style="width: 300px">
    <option></option>
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```